# Java MANIFEST.MF long lines tolerant parser

Tags: java

Does anyone know of a MANIFEST.MF parser library which tolerates long lines over the 72 character limit? I would also need a serialization back to file.

Comment: I'd suggest writing a simple preprocessor which fixes invalid files, then you can use any parser.

Answer (score 0):

I could not found any library that would allow me to serialize overlong lines. But at least I found that Apache Ant's Manifest class can read the overlong lines. The parser is at https://gitbox.apache.org/repos/asf?p=ant.git;a=blob;f=src/main/org/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs/Manifest.java;h=6417a8da21b092a813fd05d34a8696cb4335c08e;hb=HEAD